# Setting a cookie that persists across a browser session for multiple domains

Tags: javascript

So I have an iframe that pops up in a lightbox and sets a cookie. I want my parent window to read the value of cookie (parent window is in another domain). Is that possible in a single browser session?

EDIT: I figured it out through using this site: https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but only for child->parent communication.

1. Read the cookie inside your iframe
2. Send the cookie to the parent window. You can do it with `window.postMessage`
3. You have to implement an `eventHandler` on your parent window too.

Check out that page it provides all the information you need:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Just to confirm, my child window (the iframe that's in a lightbox) can send the cookie back to my parent window which is my website? Correct?

Comment: yes, it doesn't matter where the iframe is, it could be a 1x1px in the footer also. Both websites should be 'yours' in some sense, because you have to implement the communication on both ends.

Comment: But if the cookie is created inside the iframe, what code would I use to send it back to the parent? I'm confused because the examples seem to go from the parent to the iframe and not the other way around, which is what I want.

Comment: Ended up figuring it out, this site helped a lot -- https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe